# convert comma seperated values into specified json format

Tags: javascript, tags

i am using a plugin called taggle.js for managing tags i am working on available tags it displays the some tags on page load i made an ajax request and retrieved the data and the data is in comma seperated values like

```
OE,SLOTTED AND CROSSED DRILLED,JUST SLOTTED
```

now the plugin is using the following format

```
obj_buttons=['OE','SLOTTED AND CROSSED DRILLED','JUST SLOTTED'];
```

how can i convert this comma seperated string into the specified format i am using this code

```
var mystring=data.buttons;//values received from ajax in format OE,SLOTTED AND CROSSED DRILLED,JUST SLOTTED
var json = [];
var to = mystring;
var toSplit = to.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < toSplit.length; i++) {
    json.push(toSplit[i]);
}
        alert(json);
     }
```

any sort of help will be appreciated

Comment: `var obj_buttons = mystring.split(",");` is enough.

Comment: To convert your array to a JSON string try `JSON.stringify(yourArray);`

Comment: yea but the json format is incorrect inside loop it is returning OE,SLOTTED AND CROSSED DRILLED,JUST SLOTTED as it is

Comment: no david it is still incorrect firstly i dont have an array secondly this solution just puts double quotes at  starting and ending not what i ma looking for i want them to be in format obj_buttons=['OE','SLOTTED AND CROSSED DRILLED','JUST SLOTTED'];

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following method **Pass your string to this function** this will out put the json you need.

```
function commatoJson(obj_buttons){

  var lines= obj_buttons.split("\n");

  var result = [];

  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

      var obj = {};
      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }

      result.push(obj);

  }

  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```

See this for more information https://gist.github.com/iwek/7154578

For a simple string without key/value pairs

```
 alert(commatoJson("OE,SLOTTED AND CROSSED DRILLED,JUST SLOTTED"));

 function commatoJson(obj_buttons){
  var result = [];
  var headers=obj_buttons.split(",");
      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
          result.push(headers[j]);
      }
  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```

Comment: it is returning null here's the fiddle of your code https://jsfiddle.net/ub3ub2wk/

Comment: In the above way you need to pass as a table like "name, id"\n "David, 1" So this will make key value pair when you want to capture it makes process easier.

Comment: the simple string is stil returning null here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ub3ub2wk/

Comment: Sry remove the obj since your not creating objects I'll edit

Comment: ` alert(commatoJson("1,2,3\nOE,SLOTTED AND CROSSED DRILLED,JUST SLOTTED"));
   
   function commatoJson(obj_buttons){

  var lines= obj_buttons.split("\n");

  var result = [];

  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

      var obj = {};
      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }

      result.push(obj);

  }

  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
` **for sophisticated**

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to convert an object to string, there is a stringify   function to accomplish it:

```
    var mystring = "OE,SLOTTED AND CROSSED DRILLED,JUST SLOTTED";
    var json = [];
    var to = mystring;
    var toSplit = to.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < toSplit.length; i++) {
        json.push(toSplit[i]);
    }
    var result = JSON.stringify(json);
    alert(result);
```

To replace double quotes with single you can use replace with regex:

```
    json = JSON.stringify(json);
    json = json.replace(/(\")/g, "'");
    alert(json);
```

Comment: Angou it is converting the string as expected but the issue is my plugin is not accepting this format and the only difference between these two format are double quotes our current solution is outputting string with double quotes whereas originally it is using single quotes

Comment: Ok, i added quotes replace, check it out